# How to trigger flink checkpoint on custom time?

Tags: apache-flink

My case is pretty simple, I need to trigger flink checkpoint every 5 minutes, this can be done by:

```
env.enableCheckpointing(5m)
```

Moreover, I want the checkpoint to stick to x:00, x:05, x:10, ..., any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to guarantee that checkpoints will be taken at specific times.

You could, as an alternative, use a cron job to initiate savepoints at specific times, but there are some important differences between checkpoints and savepoints which might render this workaround undesirable.